# Как сохранить сгенерированную страницу php по клику кнопки?

Tags: php

Что за день-то такой. Полинета облазил, найти не смог. Есть страница. Нужно её сохранить на компьютере по кнопке.
И `fputs` попробовал, и `ob_start`.

Подскажите, люди добрые, как сохранить текущую страницу?

Comment: хм, можно попробовать загрузить Curl'om саму себя и записать в файл

Comment: или через JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        header('Content-Type: text/x-csv; charset=utf-8');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".date("d-m-Y")."-export.xls");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

Comment: @anunak, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.